# How to find if a word is present before a given word with regex?

Tags: regex

In the string "dude@here.com", I want to find if ".com" is before or after "@" using regex

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you've tried?

Comment: havent tried any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know if .com is before @, and there are no characters in between them, then the regex is

`[\.][c][o][m][@]`

If you want the same thing as above, but there can be any amount of characters in between them, then the regex is

`[\.][c][o][m][aA-zZ]*[@]`

If you want it to be the oposite, meaning that .com is *after* @, then just flip 
`[\.][c][o][m]` and `[@]`

Comment: So the * in second example means infinite number of characters?

Comment: Can I rewrite that to [.com] [aA-zZ]*[@] or .com [aA-zZ]*@

Comment: [] will match any character in the set. [com] would match c, o, or m. But not com, om, ot co. Also, * means that the expression before it can appear o or more times. Not that the * repressions 0 or more characters. Scroll down to Quantification if you go to this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression to learn more about the *.

Comment: I need to check the string ".com" so should I write [.com] or .com ? And if I put any number instead of * would it be true if the character before it is present exactly that many times ?

Comment: For the first question, yes. Also, you will need to escape(add a \ before the character) the `.` before com, because it represents `any character`, for example, he..o would match he- and then _any_ 2 characters, then o. For your second question, if you replace * with a number, then you need to wrap it in {} brackets. For example, `he(ll){2}o` would _only_ match hellllo(the parenthases are used to group the ll). If you want a range, then you can do `{min, max}`. If you want only a minimum, then you can use `{min, }`.

Comment: I want to use a regex with test() method that returns true if there is exactly one "@" or returns false. I tried /@{1}/g which returned true when I had a minimum of 1 "@" .

Comment: `^[^@]*@[^@]*$` Would work. Explanation:

`^` = Represents start of line.

`[^@]*` = In this case, ^ means the next character is not present. So, Any character except @ any number of times.

`@` = the @ character needs to be present once.

`[^@]*` = same as the first time, but has to be after @.

`$` = marks the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

`/@(?=.*\.com)/` Will work for you.

*Explanation* The above regex will check if (any characters).com is followed by '@'. (?=) This means positive look ahead in regular expression.

```js
const regex = /@(?=.*\.com)/;

console.log(regex.test("dude@here.com"));
console.log(regex.test("dude@.com"));
console.log(regex.test("someone@com"));
console.log(regex.test("here.com@dude"));
```

Comment: will this be true if the string is ".comdude@here" ?